# PHP website not working as expected in NGINX but working in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, php-fpm

Hi I just created a link shortening app. But when I try to redirect a shorten link to the full URL which is shared on Facebook it is not working as expected.
for example : https://bowa.me/c8443 this link is working fine
but if i share the link in Facebook and and the link will be like this
https://bowa.me/c8443?fbclid=IwAR0Zm8bGRgrbpQTUX_aVXxTMNFq6-MlRFe0j8e_7wm4anbWmvArPlyDaAHI This link is not redirecting

nginx config

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
         }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
      }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/admin/(.*)?$ /admin/index.php?a=$1 break;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?a=$1 last;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You should be using `try_files`, not `if (!-e $request_filename) ...`

Comment: I am using 'if (!-e $request_filename) ..' because previously it was downloading the page instead of redirecting. I have found this solution in a forum. the first link I have shared working perfectly. but the second one is not. and both are working in apache (xampp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nginx, things should be done by following nginx best practices, not trying to convert Apache2 practices to nginx. That is a recipe for all kinds of problems.

You should try the following approach:

```
# block for processing PHP files
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

# Capture part after admin to variable and use in try_files
location ~ ^/admin/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?a=$1;
}

# Default location, capture URI part and use as argument
location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?a=$1;
}
```

The order is important, nginx uses the first regular expression match from `location` blocks it finds.